# Why do my background images stay fixed when I have them set to scroll?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, elementor

I'm using AccessPress theme with Elementor plugin on WordPress.

I would like to have images on my page scroll with the page (as they do on a normal Website), but they are staying fixed and giving the "parallax" effect.

Example: https://youmeitea.com/faq/

Furthermore, I notice that when I load the page, the image loads in one position, but then jumps to another position. I would like to be able to use the custom offset in Elementor to position the image so that I can control which bit of image is visible behind the page title (refer to the example page).

I am unsure if these are related, but I suspect they might be. I have tried inspecting and playing with things in Chrome as well as selected every possible setting in the Elementor page builder to no avail. Searching for someone with more knowledge to give me some advice.

Comment: for parallax there should be an option in design mode under background image whether to give it parallax effect or not and second custom offset in Elementor to position i think you were using script for that which obviously runs at then end of page wo you feel that put that code in header so that it loads when site load

Comment: I solved this by using the "background overlay" section instead of the "background" section. Why that works, I'm not sure.

Comment: Its because you use background overlay as pseudo code or separate div, so its the new component and did't get default styles mention in WP theme style sheet